# Post articles from pages on my blog automatically 

Tags: post, blogs, blogger, autopostback

Can I make my blog create posts from articles or from other pages automatically?

Comment: if you didnt understand the question ask me to redefine it...

Comment: Please redefine - are you trying to show other pages' content as if written by you?

Comment: of course not..im trying to show content from other pages showing the link from where i found it but automatically

Comment: Hmmm...do you have a set of pages from which you want to get updates? Or how else do you want to select the sources? (There's a lot of pages on the Internet, you can't possibly link to them all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible. no there isn't an automated tool to do it for you. plus it sounds like blatant copyright infringement.

Comment: RSS + small excerpts = automatic, questionably legal (borderline fair use? YMMV) almost-content, but then you'd essentially have a click farm. Maybe that's the point?

Comment: i dont want to make something illegal thats for sure